# Android "Tooltip"

Tags: android

The current Android YouTube application provides helpful hints for navigating the user interface. For example: the first time the user switches between tabs while a video is playing, a small "tooltip" with an arrow pops up and says "You can also switch between tabs by swiping left and right." or something to that effect. Is there a way to mimic the look and functionality of this tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think of doing that is having something in a preferences file and when the user triggers a certain event (pressing a tab in Youtube rather than swiping) it brings up a custom view or even a Toast message. Then, after the tooltip is triggered, set the specific tag in the preferences file as triggered.

Comment: I was more so referring to the look of the tooltip, and the ability to position it anywhere on the screen, which was not quite clear. I edited the original question.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Could you possible make a FrameLayout that is placed on top of your main view when the certain action is performed? Then, once the user dismisses it or something, just hide or get rid of the view. Here's more on the FrameLayout: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html