# Display balloon tip in Android activity

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm curious to implement a balloon tip to show info of different UI elements in an activity. How can I achieve this? On some little effort put to this (correct me if I'm wrong please) using something like `canvas rectF`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to create tooltip text. This isn't built-in to the View classes in android, so you'll have to create them or use a library like [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid). This has already been addressed, see the following:

[android how to make Tooltip for TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039837/android-how-to-make-tooltip-for-textview)

[Android "Tooltip"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300779/android-tooltip)

Comment: Thank lot, i did not know its exact android term called, that had led to addeessing twice. :) sorry!

Comment: QuickAction dialog is the best suitable in this case.